# Add keras regularizors to a tensorflow loss function

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm gradually switching from using only Tensorflow to Tensorflow+Keras. For now I'm still training with a tensorflow optimizer, but using `Dense` layers from Keras. e.g.,

`model.add(Dense(hidden_width, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))`

How can I retrieve all the l2 penalities from my Dense Keras layers so that I can add them to my overall loss function?

Before I was using Keras, I used to do

```
reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
loss = recon_loss + sum(reg_losses)
```

But now that I'm using Keras for my Dense layers, `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` is empty.

Comment: Did not you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

All regularizers are named following the same template `{weight|bias|activation}_regularizer`.
You could try to retrieve them by filtering the losses of a model:

```py
model = Model(...)

reg_losses = [l for l in model.losses
              if 'regularizer' in l.name]
loss = recon_loss + sum(reg_losses)
```